# Search Application Topology (content processing error) SharePoint 2013

Tags: sharepoint-server

I want to ask about SharePoint issue.

Search Application Topology (content processing error)on SharePoint 2013.

[image: This the error]

what should I do to fix that issue?

Comment: did you restart search service ever? without stop crawling ?

Comment: no i didn't restart the search service and how to restart the service? thank you

Comment: Actually no need to restart the service it cause of problem may be

Comment: you can restart the service from the central administration -> Systems Settings -> Services on Server and find the "SharePoint Server Search" service.

Comment: Hi Marcelo, i've tried to restart Sharepoint Server Search from central administration. but if i click stop, the page go to search application service. any advice to restart the sharepoint server search?

Thank you